# How to fix the error (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str') in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I run the python process get this errors:

```
  File "mine.py", line 1046, in <module>
    miner.serve_forever()
  File "mine.py", line 917, in serve_forever
    self.send(method = 'mining.subscribe', params = [ "%s/%s" % (USER_AGENT, '.'.join(str(p) for p in VERSION)) ])
  File "mine.py", line 729, in send
    self._socket.send(message + '\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Is this file: [nightminer.py]

You can find the complete code here
https://github.com/ricmoo/nightminer/blob/master/nightminer.py

FILE CODE:

```
    '''Sends a message to the JSON-RPC server'''

    if not self._socket:
      raise self.ClientException('Not connected')

    request = dict(id = self._message_id, method = method, params = params)
    message = json.dumps(request)
    with self._lock:
      self._requests[self._message_id] = request
      self._message_id += 1
      self._socket.send(message + '\n')

    log('JSON-RPC Server < ' + message, LEVEL_PROTOCOL)

    return request
```

Comment: You need to show your file, not just the error. Otherwise, its impossible to know what you have done.

Comment: Welcome the Stack Overflow! In order to get your question answered properly, you need to give more details.

Comment: You must convert `message + '\n'` to bytes with `(message + '\n').encode()`.

Comment: Do you understand what the message means? Do you understand why the error occurs?

Comment: I've changed to ``` (message + '\n').encode() ``` and still get the same error

Comment: You probably have it in some other line now.

Comment: But still show me this line in the error log too